# How should I reference a data property in another data property?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue instance that looks like this:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    colors: {
      green: '#73AF48',
      blue: '#1D6996',
    },
    circles: [
      { fill: '#73AF48', x:   0, y:   0 },
      { fill: '#1D6996', x:  50, y:   0 },
      { fill: '#1D6996', x: 100, y:   0 },
      { fill: '#1D6996', x:   0, y:  50 },
      { fill: '#73AF48', x:  50, y:  50 },
      { fill: '#1D6996', x: 100, y:  50 },
      { fill: '#1D6996', x:   0, y: 100 },
      { fill: '#1D6996', x:  50, y: 100 },
      { fill: '#73AF48', x: 100, y: 100 },
    ],
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 150 150">
    <g transform="translate(25 25)">
      <circle v-for="circle in circles"
              :cx="circle.x"
              :cy="circle.y"
              :fill="circle.fill"
              r="25" />
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

You can see that I'm repeating the same `fill` strings inside the `circles` array. In the interest of keeping the code DRY, I'd like to use variables for these `fill` properties.

I can think of two ways to do this:

1) Move `circles` to a computed property:

```
computed: {
  circles() {
    return [
      { fill: this.colors.green, x:   0, y:   0 },
      { fill: this.colors.blue,  x:  50, y:   0 },
      { fill: this.colors.blue,  x: 100, y:   0 },
      { fill: this.colors.blue,  x:   0, y:  50 },
      { fill: this.colors.green, x:  50, y:  50 },
      { fill: this.colors.blue,  x: 100, y:  50 },
      { fill: this.colors.blue,  x:   0, y: 100 },
      { fill: this.colors.blue,  x:  50, y: 100 },
      { fill: this.colors.green, x: 100, y: 100 },
    ];
  },
},
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    colors: {
      green: '#73AF48',
      blue: '#1D6996',
    },
  },
  computed: {
    circles() {
      return [
        { fill: this.colors.green, x:   0, y:   0 },
        { fill: this.colors.blue,  x:  50, y:   0 },
        { fill: this.colors.blue,  x: 100, y:   0 },
        { fill: this.colors.blue,  x:   0, y:  50 },
        { fill: this.colors.green, x:  50, y:  50 },
        { fill: this.colors.blue,  x: 100, y:  50 },
        { fill: this.colors.blue,  x:   0, y: 100 },
        { fill: this.colors.blue,  x:  50, y: 100 },
        { fill: this.colors.green, x: 100, y: 100 },
      ];
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 150 150">
    <g transform="translate(25 25)">
      <circle v-for="circle in circles"
              :cx="circle.x"
              :cy="circle.y"
              :fill="circle.fill"
              r="25" />
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Or 2) Make `data` a function, set the colors in a constant, and `return` the rest of the `data` object:

```
data() {
  const colors = {
    green: '#73AF48',
    blue: '#1D6996',
  };

  return {
    circles: [
      { fill: colors.green, x:   0, y:   0 },
      { fill: colors.blue,  x:  50, y:   0 },
      { fill: colors.blue,  x: 100, y:   0 },
      { fill: colors.blue,  x:   0, y:  50 },
      { fill: colors.green, x:  50, y:  50 },
      { fill: colors.blue,  x: 100, y:  50 },
      { fill: colors.blue,  x:   0, y: 100 },
      { fill: colors.blue,  x:  50, y: 100 },
      { fill: colors.green, x: 100, y: 100 },
    ],
  };
},
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    const colors = {
      green: '#73AF48',
      blue: '#1D6996',
    };
    
    return {
      circles: [
        { fill: colors.green, x:   0, y:   0 },
        { fill: colors.blue,  x:  50, y:   0 },
        { fill: colors.blue,  x: 100, y:   0 },
        { fill: colors.blue,  x:   0, y:  50 },
        { fill: colors.green, x:  50, y:  50 },
        { fill: colors.blue,  x: 100, y:  50 },
        { fill: colors.blue,  x:   0, y: 100 },
        { fill: colors.blue,  x:  50, y: 100 },
        { fill: colors.green, x: 100, y: 100 },
      ],
    };
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 150 150">
    <g transform="translate(25 25)">
      <circle v-for="circle in circles"
              :cx="circle.x"
              :cy="circle.y"
              :fill="circle.fill"
              r="25" />
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Both of these methods work, but both of them kinda smell to me. How are cases like this handled in Vue?

Comment: `data` is _supposed_ to be a function in Vue...

Comment: The [official docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function) say "a **component’s** `data` option must be a function" (emphasis mine). In this case, `data` isn't inside a component. Everywhere else in the docs, `data` is an object, not a function.

Comment: You can simply define a variable that holds your colors object before you instantiate Vue.

Comment: "Everywhere else" being what? If we aren't talking about the `data` property of a Vue component, are we talking about the `data` property of your own data store or random data structure? In that case, you can make it whatever you want it to be. DRY is a great design principle, but don't use it as an excuse to prematurely optimize.

Comment: When I said everywhere else, I meant everywhere in the docs that `data` isn't inside a component. For example: The [Declarative Rendering](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html#Declarative-Rendering), [Conditionals and Loops](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html#Conditionals-and-Loops), and [Instance Lifecycle Hooks](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks) sections.

Comment: If I define a variable before instantiating Vue, or inside the `data` function, can I easily change the colors later at runtime? If I want to change blue to be a darker shade, I don't see an easy way to do it and have it render live.

Comment: @Travis Vue 2.6 has a new API [Vue.obserevable(object)](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-observable). Might be what you're looking for.

Comment: It seems like you have your answer, then. If the `data` property is in a component, make it a function. Otherwise, make it an object. That much doesn't seem like it's negotiable.